# Angular 2+ component documentation preview in HTML

Tags: angular, webstorm, documentation

I am wondering if it is possible to write documentation for angular components that will be displayed as a tooltip when adding a new component in HTML. I am using Webstorm.

I mean:

If I have component A

```
/**
 * This is the documentation intended to be shown in the tooltip.
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'app-a',
  templateUrl: './a.html',
  styleUrls: ['./a.scss']
})
export class AComponent {
  constructor() { }
}
```

In the HTML of the component B

```html
  <app-a></app-a>
```

I expect to see the doc of the component by hovering or using the show documentation shortcut of my IDE.

(my result)
[image]

(result expected)
[image]

Comment: Have you made a feature request to JetBrains? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: @RandyCasburn so you are saying that it is not possible to achieve that right now and I have to ask the JetBrains team for an implementation?

Comment: this is not currently possible AFAIK and there are no plugins that provide this capability.

Comment: You should also realize that DOC BLOC you've shown above documents the following class `AComponent` - not an external HTML file custom Angular Element. There is no mechanism (or type)  in JSDOC or TypeDoc  that would document an external entity, let alone HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such feature in the IDE; we plan to add it in one of the nearest IDE updates, the progress can be tracked at [WEB-43480](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-43480)